# SQL Server: intrigued by GETDATE()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have SQL Server 2005 Standard Service Pack 2  9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86)

Table has close to 30 million rows..

If I do

```
SELECT GETDATE(), * FROM
<table>
```

**Identical Date and time value is returned including milliseconds part**.. though query took more then 3 minutes to complete...

I have already read

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/02/27/when-getdate-is-not-a-constant.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/66507b8b-4a74-44c1-9637-3ab5f75db6a0

One of the link I posted (marked answer) suggest that prior to SQL 2005 GETDATE was deterministic 
although SQL 2000 BOL states GETDATE is nondeterministic

If I do an update with millions of rows

```
UPDATE tableName
SET dateColumn = GETDATE()
```

I know you really want to do

```
DECLARE @DT datetime
SET @DT = GETDATE()
UPDATE table
SET datecol =@DT
```

I am really confused

What would be expected behavior?

1. In case of select statement  I posted earlier
2. Behavior of update statement

Considering you are updateing a datecolun on a table with 100 million rows 
Would datecolumn will have identical date and time in milliseconds....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from Martin Smith's answer, The determinism referred to was a change in udf behaviour. In SQL Server 2000, you could not use GETDATE in a udf. You can in SQL Server 2005. [See this link too](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/23/sql-server-2005-use-of-non-deterministic-function-in-udf-find-day-difference-between-any-date-and-today/)

As Martin Smith said, some functions are evaluated per column, per query. Not per row. GETDATE is one, RAND is another.

If you do need row by row evaluation of GETDATE then wrap it in udf.

Edit:

NEWID is statistically unique. It must be evaluated row by row so you don't have the same value appear in another row. Hence the `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` trick to generate row by row random numbers...

Comment: Thanks but Why not NEWID behaves differenly?

SELECT top 4 newid(), newid()
from sys.objects

Comment: now I understand as if you want to return rows randomly 

then  
ORDER BY NEWID() 

so newid() is different...

Comment: What would update behaves same? ie. UPDATE tableName SET dateColumn = GETDATE() 

OK it will same.. dumb :-(

Answer (score 11):

`GetDate()` was never deterministic. Deterministic means that it will always return the same result when passed the same parameters.

In common with `rand()` It is evaluated once *per column* but once evaluated remains the same for all rows.

It is easier to see this behaviour with `rand()` than `getdate()`

```
select top 4 rand(), rand()
from sys.objects
```

Returned

```
---------------------- ----------------------
0.0566172633850772     0.431111195699363
0.0566172633850772     0.431111195699363
0.0566172633850772     0.431111195699363
0.0566172633850772     0.431111195699363
```

If you try the following

```
select top 10 getdate(), getdate()
from sys.objects
```

and look at the ComputeScalar operator properties in the actual execution plan you will see that `GetDate()` is evaluated twice.

NB: It is possible that this behaviour of evaluation per column rather than per query changed after SQL 2000 (I don't know) but that isn't what BOL defines as the meaning of deterministic.

Comment: Martin, how come NEWID() return different result?

Comment: @cshah - Good question and one I don't know the answer to!

Comment: @cshah, @Martin Smith: please see my answer for NEWID

Comment: +1: I was able to verify the behavior you mentioned (SQL Server 2008) by throwing a few thousand `RAND()s` between the two getdate()s. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036223/will-getutcdate-return-the-same-value-if-used-twice-in-the-same-statement/6036783#6036783